# Rails ActiveAdmin adding multiple rows for one row header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to show multiple objects in rows with one row header like the one on the photo but I can't show another user under 'Theresa Mendoza'.

[ActiveAdmin Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTfa4.png)

Here's my current code:

```
row('Staff Users') do |v|
  if v.staff_users.present?
    v.staff_users.first.full_name
  end
end
```

I tried doing it like the code below however it doesn't work:

```
  if vendor.staff_users.present?
    vendor.staff_users.each do |u|
      row('') do
        u.full_name
      end 
    end 
  end
```

Anyone has any idea how I can work around this?
Thanks!

Edit: If I remove `.first` in the line `v.staff_users.first_full_name` this error will show:

[Active Admin Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeOws.png)

Comment: what do you have as result if you just use this code:      vendor.staff_users.each do |u|

        u.full_name

    end

Comment: @Nezir it's presents an error. let me check again what and I'll update the post with it

Comment: can you check content of vendor.staff_users? by using byebug or pry debugger or go to rails c  console and with query check what do you exactly get here

Comment: @Nezir it's an array of objects

Comment: okay give me few minutes to check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show it in a table something like this -

```
  table_for(vendor.staff_users) do
    column :full_name do |resource|
      resource.full_name
    end
  end
```

Comment: this solution works, not as I wanted but it's a workaround! thanks!